# Android NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library onCharacteristicChanged is not called

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I'm using this library 
[NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library) for BLE communication and successfully able to connect the peripheral device. I'm getting the services and characteristics and able to write the characteristics.

But for somehow after writing the characteristics the ***onCharacteristicChanged*** is not called. Though I enable the notifications first and than write.

This is how I'm enabling it with new version of library.

```
setNotificationCallback(bluetoothGattCharacteristic).with(object : ProfileDataCallback {
        override fun onDataReceived(device: BluetoothDevice, data: Data) {
            BluetoothNotificationBus.getBus().post(BluetoothNotificationEvents.PostPeripheralValueForCharacteristicChangedNotification(device,bluetoothGattCharacteristic.service,bluetoothGattCharacteristic))
        }

        override fun onInvalidDataReceived(device: BluetoothDevice, data: Data) {
            BluetoothNotificationBus.getBus().post(BluetoothNotificationEvents.PostPeripheralValueForCharacteristicChangedNotification(device,bluetoothGattCharacteristic.service,bluetoothGattCharacteristic))
        }

    })
enableNotifications(bluetoothGattCharacteristic).enqueue()
```

**Also in logcat:**

```
2019-05-20 14:03:24.110 6148-6148/com.nextmunich.trumaandroidpoc D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: f47b0100-f3b2-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1 enable: true
```

Also from **BleManager.java**, below method returns **true**

```
@MainThread
private boolean internalEnableNotifications(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final BluetoothGatt gatt = mBluetoothGatt;
    if (gatt == null || characteristic == null || !mConnected)
        return false;

    final BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = getCccd(characteristic, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
    if (descriptor != null) {
        log(Log.DEBUG, "gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(" + characteristic.getUuid() + ", true)");
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        log(Log.VERBOSE, "Enabling notifications for " + characteristic.getUuid());
        log(Log.DEBUG, "gatt.writeDescriptor(" + CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR_UUID + ", value=0x01-00)");
        return internalWriteDescriptorWorkaround(descriptor);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please guide to overcome this issue. As I know there are different threads on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.

I've also test my code with  [nRF Connect App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) and it seems notification works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by *after writing the characteristics*? I understand your Android device has the client / central manager role. So it would enable notifications, wait for notifications and process the data recevied as part of the notification. If it writes a characteristic, it will not get any notification for it. The peripheral / server on the other hand writes to the characteristic with notifications enabled.

Comment: notifications are enabled on the peripheral and it works fine on iOS but not getting notified in Android